# Ionic Schedule a Popover page to display every N days

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am looking to display a page every N days or for example every 3/4 days which will just popover the screen

So far from digging about I see ionics local notifications offers a really nice way to schedule standard notifications within an app but it does not allow you to change the notification data to use a page.

Is there a way to do this kind of thing natively within ionic ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a `popover`? Couldn't you just keep a record of the last time the page was show to the user using `localStorage` or `Storage` and when the app is launched check if it's time to show the page again and then redirect to that page. If you do want it to be a `popover` it's pretty simple. You create the page like normal then add it as the `component` in your poperover constructor. Something like this in your `platform.ready()`:

```
 const daysSinceLastShown = parseint(localStorage.get('daysSinceLastShown'), 10);
 if (daysSinceLastShown < 4) {
     daysSinceLastShown++;
     localStorage.put('daysSinceLastShown', daysSinceLastShown);
 } else {
     localStorage.put('daysSinceLastShown', 0);
     presentPopover();
 }

 async presentPopover() {
     const popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
         component: MyPopoverPage,
     });
     return await popover.present();
 }
```